# What is the best way to consume REST APIs from DTSX packages?

Tags: .net, sql-server, rest, ssis, servicestack

We have recently migrated our SOAP services into REST APIs. With that, we had changed all consumers to point to new REST APIs successfully. However, there are some integration services packages (DTSX) in our setup which are currently invoking those SOAP services. These dtsx packages are being invoked from SQL Server Job steps.

I tried to find out ways to invoke REST APIs from DTSX packages, but most of the blogs suggest to write C# code for that, which seems to be a major change as there are many packages. I wonder there must be some method similar to invoking SOAP services from dtsx packages, that would enable us this migration more efficient and with less change/ efforts.

Could anyone please help out with the best possible way to consume REST APIs from dtsx packages (Except, writing a C# program)?

Our REST APIs are developed using ServiceStack, if that information helps!

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Afraid not,you will need a c# script component (as a source) in a data flow task to achieve this, there aren't any pre-built components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using third party components you will need to write your own `Script Source Component` using either C# or VB.Net.  The good news however, is that once you have written the component it can be copied and pasted into other packages and used just as you would any other data source.

Writing the C# is also not a big deviation from normal SSIS workflow or design and shouldn't require much more rework than converting your SOAP consuming transformations a REST consuming transformation, assuming one exists for your purpose.  Either way, you are going to need to edit each and every package to consume the new source.

Answer (score 0):

If third-party components are an option, ZappySys makes an excellent REST API task, part of their SSIS PowerPack. I have used it with great success on multiple projects.